# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" without "when expecting ..."

Tags: oracle, if-statement, plsql

I get "Encountered the symbol "IF"" error without any "when expecting ..." after that. My simplified code looks like this:

```
declare
begin
 with ()
 select <some value> into My_output
 EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND then
  My_output := NULL;
 END;
 if My_output is not NULL then
  <Statement>
 end if;
end;
```

Comment: The `if` is after the `end`of the block, but as you’ve simplified your code - there’s nothing in the declare section for instance - maybe that’s a sub-block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making some assumptions about the bits you’ve left out, you are ending the PL/SQL block and then have more code. Given your exception handler, it looks like that was supposed to be a sub-block:

```
declare
  My_output <some type>;
begin /* main block */
  begin /* sub-block - this was missing */
    with ()
    select <some value> into My_output
  EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND then
    My_output := NULL;
  END; /* sub-block */
  if My_output is not NULL then
    <Statement>
  end if;
end; /* main block*/
```

You could potentially use an aggregate min/max instead of an exception handler, if you know there will zero or one result. That would handle multiple results differently though - this version would get too-many-rows.

If the selected value can’t itself be null, you could also put the `<statement>` inside the sub-block instead of its own ‘if’ section.

But both off-topic, and hard to tell how much it’s been simplified of course...